# How to replace part of a strings (multiple) in which, each have separate condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Employee which has following columns and values.

```
ID   FNAME       LNAME       CITY

1    Shahriar    Ahmed       Dhaka
2    Mamunur     Rashid      Natore, Rajshahi
3    Muntasir    Shafiq      Bogra, Rajshahi
```

I need to change the part of CITY 'Rajshahi' to 'Northen Rajshahi' who has FNAME = Mamunur and LNAME = Rashid

and part of CITY 'Rajshahi' to 'Southern Rajshahi' who has FNAME = Muntasir and LNAME = Shafiq

I have tried as a newbie and those are seems to be meaning less to show up here,

Could someone help me to get over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use REPLACE function as it searches for certain characters in a string and replaces them with other characters.Furtermore,
you could use CASE expression to fulfill differnt condition of replacement.

```
UPDATE Employee
SET  CITY = (CASE  
             WHEN FNAME = 'Mamunur' AND LNAME = 'Rashid' 
                  THEN REPLACE(city, 'Rajshahi', 'Northern Rajshahi') 
             WHEN FNAME = 'Muntasir' AND LNAME = 'Shafiq' 
                  THEN REPLACE(city, 'Rajshahi', 'Southern Rajshahi')            
             ELSE CITY
         END 
         );
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO HERE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/501050)</kbd>

For further study go on,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using two `UPDATE` statements:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET CITY = REPLACE(CITY, 'Rajshahi', 'Northern Rajshahi')
WHERE FNAME = 'Mamunur' AND LNAME = 'Rashid'

UPDATE Employee
SET CITY = REPLACE(CITY, 'Rajshahi', 'Southern Rajshahi')
WHERE FNAME = 'Muntasir' AND LNAME = 'Shafiq'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.